# Chart.JS tension options looks weird

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm using ChartJS v4.0.1. They've implemented a new option to curve the line chart named `tension`. But it looks so weird.

The option value works between 0 and 1, I've tried several options to make the Chart more beauty and here we are:

---

```
tension: 0.1
```

[image]

---

```
tension: 0.5
```

[image]

---

```
tension: 1
```

[image]

---

So my question is, what can I do to make the chart more "smooth", something like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `cubicInterpolationMode`. It is documented here: [Line Chart | Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.0.1/charts/line.html#cubicinterpolationmode)

Your line looks a bit smoother here:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset',
      data: [1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
      cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone' // <--- HERE
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: [1, 2, 3]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.0.1"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```